# Difference between attr and prop when call eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, attr, prop

I use jquery-1.12.4 library, and call eval() like this:

```
var obj = $(this).find('ul');    
if ($(this).prop('class').substring(0,1) == 'c') {  
        eval(obj.attr('url'));
        console.log(obj.prop('url'))
        console.log(obj.attr('url'))
    } else {
        eval(obj.prop('clr'));
        obj.html('');
    }
```

I think the return will be the same, but actually not, they returned:

```
console.log(obj.prop('url')) //undefined

console.log(obj.attr('url')) //req_subfolder('/', '_', '1')
```

"req_subfolder('/', '_', '1')" is what I want to get, but why can't I use prop() to get what I want? Is it because I call eval()?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that part, updated, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because `prop()` retrieves properties of the Element object within the jQuery object and `url` is not a valid property.

If you want to define your own data on an element I'd suggest you use `data-*` instead, like this:

```js
console.log($('div').data('url'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-url="/foobar"></div>
```

Comment: Thx! It worked! Trying to figure out the difference between prop/attr/data, thx a lot! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For your reference: http://api.jquery.com/prop, http://api.jquery.com/attr, http://api.jquery.com/data